# .htaccess rewrite condition to redirect links from http to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a lot of different links without any logical rules, that are redirected with .htaccess `Redirect 301`

.htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysyte.com

    Redirect 301 /oldlink1 /newlink1
    Redirect 301 /oldlink1 /newlink1
    Redirect 301 /oldlink1 /newlink1

    ...
```

Some days ago I've set up https. Unfortunately, `https://mysyte.com/oldlink...` redirects to `http://mysyte.com/newlink...` - not to https but http.

What i'm doing wrong? How should I set up .htaccess file to redirect to https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're changing protocols or sites, then you HAVE to use an absolute url:

```
Redirect 301 /oldlink https://example.com/newlink1
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

otherwise it's just a "local" redirect and you stay within the same site/protocol.

And note that `Redirect` is NOT part of mod_rewrite. That's a core directive in Apache (part of mod_alias) and has nothing to do with mod_rewrite at all: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: I prefer relevant links like /newlink not absolute like https://example.net/newlink So question is about that

Comment: then you're stuck. you can NOT do a "local" redirect and expect the host or protocol to change. You **HAVE** to make it an absolute url for `Redirect`. and like i said, redirect is NOT part of mod_rewrite, and mod_rewrite semantics don't apply to it.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I'm trying to open link directly (type https://example.com/oldlink1 in address bar) redirect 301 opens page with http protocol (http://example.com/newlink1). But when I'm opening the same link from https page (in <img src) - it open's https ...

Comment: because `/oldlink /newlink` is a RELATIVE direct. it's exactly the same as having `<a href="/newlink">click here to go to new address</a>` in your html. there's no hostname. there's no protocol, so that's extracted from the address of the CURRENT page, which is `http`